# Assistance needed with a inheritance and constructor code

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am working on an inheritance problem. I have a super class of Book. Then I have a class Phone that extends book. Then I have a drive PolyMain that uses an array to generate an output. I was tasked with the following:

*The constructor of the Phone class should sum up whitePages + yellowPages to get the total number of pages in the book and pass this to the Book superclass as a single parameter in a super call. Remember the total pages in the book and the title of the book are set in the constructor for the Book class.

Modify the PolyMain class to create at least one of your phone books and store it in the library. You should now be able to print the library without having to modify the print method defined within the PolyMain class.*

The out put should have the title, # of pages (total), # of yellow pages and # white pages. The program below gives me that output.

However, the PolyMain has integers added Example: library[2] = new Novel("Animal Farm ", 250, 9); The "250 and 9"have been added and that's what prints for pages and chapters.

How am I to be sure that my constructor is summing up the yellowPages and whitePages if I have to add the numbers to the PolyMain class?
library[3] = new Phone("Black Hills Directory ", 600, 350, 250);
If I don't add "600, 350, 250" or some integers I get an error and it won't compile.

***Here is the code for the super class:***

```
public class Book  
{   
  private String title;     
  private int pages;    

  public Book(String title, int pages)    
  {     
   this.title = new String(title);      
   setPages(pages);   
  }    

 public void setPages(int pages)    
 {     
  this.pages = pages;   
 }    
 public int getPages()    
 {      
  return pages;    
 }    
 public void print()    
 {     
  System.out.print(title + " has " + pages + " pages");   
  } 
}
```

**Here is my child class.**

```
public class Phone extends Book  
{   
    private int yellowPages = 250;
    private int whitePages = 350;


 public Phone (String title, int pages, int whitePages, int yellowPages)    
{  
  super(title, pages);  

   this.whitePages = whitePages;
   this.yellowPages = yellowPages;
   pages = whitePages + yellowPages; 
  }    
 public void print()    
 {     
  super.print();     
  System.out.println(", " + yellowPages + " yellowPages, " + "and " +
                    whitePages + " whitePages." );   
 }
```

}

**Here is my driver class.**

```
 public class PolyMain  
 {   
 public static void main(String [] args)    
 {     
  Book [] library = new Book [5];      
  library[0] = new Novel("Jaws", 300, 15);     
  library[1] = new Almanac("New World ", 100, 50);     
  library[2] = new Novel("Animal Farm ", 250, 9); 
  library[3] = new Phone("Black Hills Directory ", 600, 350, 250);   
  listBooks(library);    
 }     
  static void listBooks(Book [] library)    
 {     
  for (int i = 0; i < library.length && library[i] != null; i++)       
    library[i].print();    
 }     
}
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, but you don't need the `600`/`pages` parameter because in the constructor you can call `super(title, whitePages + yellowPages)`.

Comment: @Ken Y-N. Thank you for the pointer, but I don't quite get it. If I pull the "600/350/250/" from the object, I get an error stating that my Phone method is set up with "string, int, int, int". I seem to be in a catch 22. If I modify Phone it messes up PolyMain and I can't modify PolyMain without modifying Phone. No matter how I edit it, I get errors. Can you explain? Please and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your specs say it all "The constructor of the Phone class should sum up whitePages + yellowPages to get the total number of pages in the book and pass this to the Book superclass as a single parameter in a super call."

You can set your Phone constructor with just 3 parameters - title, white pages, and yellow pages

Now call the super class' constructor using the title as title and whitePages+yellowPages as pages

Comment: +mikbzon Thank you. I am still unclear on the driver class which creates a new phone object.

Comment: Thank you. I am still unclear on the driver class which creates a new phone object.library[3] = new Phone("Hot Springs Directory ", 600, 350, 250); When I pull the numbers (600, 350, 250)  out of there, I get an error. I am not sure how to modify the constructor in Phone and the object in PolyMain to get them to work.